# App icon missing in "more" menu for Share Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, share-extension

[image: Missing Icon]

iOS: 16

Xcode: 14.2

I cannot figure out why my app icon is showing everywhere except the more menu in Share Extensions.

I'm using an Asset catalogue, with a file named "AppIcon" that uses the new 1024x1024 app icon sizing. This Asset catalogue is shared between my iOS app and Share Extension.

I even changed the "Primary App Icon Set Name" to AppIcon in my Share Extension to match my App but no luck.

Anyone else had this issue?

EDIT: Plot twist - the icon appears correctly in the simulator but not on device